# Is this correct? "How do you not be too hard on yourself for realizing you tolerated poor behavior in a relationship?"

Tags: grammar, verbs, modal-verbs

This is the title of a post I saw on Reddit

> "***How do you not be too hard on yourself for realizing you tolerated
>   poor behavior in a relationship?"***

and I was wondering if "do you not be" was correct. It sounds a bit odd to me, shouldn't it be; e.g

> "How can you not be too hard on yourself...?"

*or*

> "How can you try not to be too hard on yourself...?"

Answer (score 1):

All three example sentences in the original post are grammatically correct.  The original poster is correct that the proposed alternatives are more natural than the first example.

Comment: I agree. That said, many folks don't spend much time proofreading, revising, or polishing what they post on Reddit.